# Get records between two String dates

Tags: java, sql, date, ms-access

I know that data type of Date column should be Date/Time, but in my case it is Text.

Now I want to fetch records between two dates.

```
String Date1=jTextField.getText();
String Date2=jTextField2.getText();

pre=conn.prepareStatement("select * from Table where Date between "Date1" and "Date2"");

ResultSet rs=pre.executeQuery();
```

I know that this query does not help me. But I am totally new to sql query so please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

I am using MS Access Database.

At this stage I am just printing records using System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

Comment: Please post the rest of your code, also which relational database. We will also need the text format of your date(s).

Comment: You will need to use SQL `conversion` functions (or `casting`) of your particular database engine.

Comment: @PM77-1 Not necessarily. Might use `SimpleDateFormat` in Java.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Only if date representation in text fields is very consistent (since OP will be dealing with `string` comparison).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CDate](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/datatype/cdate.php) function, and the [ORDER BY](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/order-by-clause-HP001032258.aspx) is

```
// Java style variable names.
String date1 = jTextField.getText();
String date2 = jTextField2.getText();

// using CDate...
pre=conn.prepareStatement("select * from Table where Date "
    + "between CDate(?) and CDate(?) order by Date");
pre.setString(1, date1); // bind param 1
pre.setString(2, date2); // bind param 2

ResultSet rs=pre.executeQuery();
```

It is also possible to convert the String(s) into Date(s) in Java using a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), but that solution is more complex. At this point, you should probably stick with the simplest (correct) solution.

Comment: Sir Thank you so much, You save me. Please do one more thing please provide me order by Date clause

Comment: Sir I am back again. Sir this query is not help me for dates 01/12/2013 to 31/01/2014

Comment: @user3159272 You should probably post another question, but that second one isn't a valid date format (probably)... did you read the link to [CDate](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/datatype/cdate.php)?

Comment: If we take date like 01/01/2014 to 31/12/2014 then it gives me record from all dates from 2013 also.

Comment: @user3159272 Try "01/01/2014" to "12/31/2014" - I don't think your format is correct.

Comment: How can we use "01/01/2014" to "12/31/2014"  Bcoz our dates are in string variables

Comment: I did ask you for the date format right? You could use two SimpleDateFormat instances.

Comment: @MessyProgrammer - the format used in the database is important because there isn't a single way to encode dates as strings. With respect to a previous example, I'm British and so would write 31/01/2014; an American would write 01/31/2014 however. Alternatively, thinking as a programmer I might use 2014-01-31 - there are many other possibles too (full stops/periods not forward slashes for the delimiter, not bothering with leading zeros, etc.).